# FFMPEG API: decode MPEG to YUV frames and change these frames

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, yuv

I need save all frames from MPEG4 or H.264 video to YUV-frames using C++ library. For example, in .yuv, .y4m or .y format. Then I need read these frames like a digital files and change some samples (Y-value). How can I do it without convert to RGB?

And how store values of AVFrame->data? Where store Y-, U- and V-values?

Thanks and sorry for my English=)

Answer (score 1):

If you use libav* to decode, you will receive the frames in their native colorspace (usually YUV 420) But it is what ever was chosen at encode time. Assuming you are in YUV420 or convert to YUV420 `y: AVFrame->data[0]`, `u: AVFrame->data[1]`, `v: AVFrame->data[2]`

For Y, 1 byte per pixel `AVFrame->data[0][(x*AVFrame->linesize[0]) + y]`
For U and V its 4 pixles per byte (quarter resolution of Y plane). So
`AVFrame->data[1][(x/2*AVFrame->linesize[1]) + y/2]`, `AVFrame->data[2][(x/2*AVFrame->linesize[2]) + y/2]`

Comment: O, thank you! And could you tell me the meaning of the `linesize`?

Comment: That is, all samples brightness stored in the array data [0] sequentially from line to line? And treatment `pFrame-> data [0] [y + pFrame-> width]` give me the first sample of the second row?

Comment: Yes, they are stored sequentially. No `y + pFrame-> width` will not give you the second row. `y + pFrame->linesize[0]` will. Line size (also called stride) is the number of bytes per line. This can be larger (but not smaller) that width, if there is padding. see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you all understand. Could you help with this issue: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039083/dwt-of-frames-by-ffmpeg-api]?